# Remove "a href" from wp_list_comments()

Tags: theme-development, comments

My current theme comments are displayed using following code.

```
         <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'      => 'ol',
                    'short_ping' => true,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol>
```

I need to remove "a href" part.I mean their should not be linked to the comment author website.

I check [`wp_list_comments()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) from codex, but I could not find how to remove `<a href` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep down the function uses [`get_comment_author_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_author_link/) to output the author name. That function is filterable. Inside the function it checks if the author has a URL and wraps the name in a link to it if it exists. We can use the `get_comment_author_link` filter to just output the name, and ignore the URL. This is pretty simple, since the callback for this filter gets the author name as one of its arguments, so we just need to pass it through untouched:

```
function wpse_284352_author_link( $author_link, $author ) {
    return $author;
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'wpse_284352_author_link', 10, 2 );
```

**EDIT:** It's actually even simpler, the URL has its own filter, which means that can be filtered with one of WordPress' built in functions in one line:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own walker and customize its structure. Note that using a filter will affect *"all"* instances of `wp_list_comments()`, so you are advised to customize your comments by using a walker. Here's a basic example:

```
function my_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment-wrap">
            <div class="comment-head comment-author vcard"><?php
                echo get_avatar( $comment, 60 );
                if ( comments_open() ){
                    comment_reply_link( 
                        array_merge( 
                            $args, 
                            array( 
                                'depth' => $depth,
                                'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'], 
                                'reply_text' => __( 'Reply' ) 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    );
                }?>
                <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                    <div class="comment-date"><?php
                        /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                        printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s' ),
                            get_comment_date(),
                            get_comment_time()
                        ); ?>
                    </div><?php
                    edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit' ), '', '' );?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-content comment-text"><?php
                if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) { ?>
                    <em><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.'); ?></em><br /><?php
                }
                comment_text(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Now you can define the callback in `wp_list_comments()`:

```
wp_list_comments( 
    array( 
        'callback' => 'my_comment' ,
        'style'    => 'ol'
    ) 
);
```

This will render the comments without a link to them. You can fully customize the output comments. Further information and complex examples are provided in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) page.

Comment: @JackJohansson I currently accepted the Jacob Peattie answer because it gives the quick solution for me. But long term wise it has problem as you said... So I will try your answers and I will mark your answer as accepted answer... Please give me a few days for that because currently I just wanted to remove `<a href` as soon as possible.